# Resume file download with Apache VFS

Tags: java, apache-commons-vfs

I have an application that uses VFS to download files over FTP or SFTP. When the file is large and the network connection is lost I currently have to start the download again.

Is it possible to do a resumable file download with VFS?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer in the commons email archives:

You can use the RandomAccessContent:

```
FileObject fo = VFS.getManager().resolveFile("ftp://..."); 
RandomAccessContent rac = fo.getContent().getRandomAccessContent(RandomAccessMode.READ);
rac.seek(4711);
```

If you need a InputStream you can aquire one by using:

```
InputStream is = rac.getInputStream();
```